# Padding issue with blueprint css

Tags: css, blueprint-css

The following markup looks fine with blueprintcss :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span-12" style="background-color : cyan">
Hello
  </div>
  <div class="span-12 last" style="background-color : green">
Bye
  </div>
</div>
```

You get two columns that takes half the size, that's neat :

```
Hello              Bye
```

Now, the 'Hello' text is too close to the edge of its container div, so you want to add a little padding, right ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span-12" style="background-color : cyan; padding-left : 5px">
Hello
  </div>
  <div class="span-12 last" style="background-color : green">
Bye
  </div>
</div>
```

Except obviously it does not work, and you end up with the "Bye" column" *under* the Hello one :

```
 Hello              
Bye
```

Reducing the size of the second column does not make sense (since I *really* want it to be "12 grid column wide".

Now, adding another level of markup work, but is it necessary ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span-12" style="background-color : cyan">
    <div style="padding-left : 5px">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="span-12 last" style="background-color : green">
Bye
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something ?

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are not using `box-sizing: border-box`. If you use that, your suggested solution should work. Otherwise, you'll need the extra level of markup.

Remember, the default for widths is to apply to the content, not the border, so when Blueprint gives a width and you give padding, the padding is *added* to the width, which is bad. The `box-sizing: border-box` directive fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the result you want, it might be possible to add `border-left: 5px` to this specific `.container`. If you have a solid color, or a solid color with `rgba()` transparency, it shouldn't make any difference to the rest of the layout.

```css
.container
{
  /* cyan is the test color */
  background-color: cyan;
  border-left: 5px;
  border-color: cyan;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Blueprint does smart stuff and is better tested than my suggestion - if this doesn't work out, I would use an inner element for the best cross-browser (old IE) results.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add another div inside the div, that way you will never run into problems.

I follow a standard of adding the inner divs the class padding

```
.padding { padding:1.5em; }
```

So in your code, this would look like this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="span-12" style="background-color : cyan">
      <div class="padding">
           Hello
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span-12 last" style="background-color : green">
       Bye
    </div>
</div>
```